# Cannot Enable Livepatch on 18.04: "cannot send request ... write operation not permitted."

Tags: canonical-livepatch

I installed Livepatch without incident, but when I tried to enable it I got this:

```
$ sudo canonical-livepatch enable [token redacted]
[sudo] password for [redacted]: 
2019/09/01 13:57:26 error executing enable: cannot enable machine: cannot send request: Post https://livepatch.canonical.com/api/machine-tokens: dial tcp: lookup livepatch.canonical.com on [::1]:53: write udp [fe80::466c:1448:d556:e7ce]:39080->[::1]:53: write: operation not permitted
```

I don't know how to decipher this. The reference to "dial tcp" is especially baffling. Is it not finding my internet connection (which is made through a USB-to-ethernet adapter)?

Comment: [Related Ubuntu Forums thread.](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420977) Is `::1` accessible? Typically it is--it's the IPv6 address for `localhost`--but, as happened to one of the users in that thread, it is possible to have a system on which the loopback interface, or some of its addresses, are deliberately or unintentionally unusable. I recommend you check this, for example by running `ping ::1`, and **[edit]** this question with details. If that doesn't work, try `ping 127.0.0.1` to test IPv4. Either way, please also include full output of `ip a` (if necessary, with redactions).

Comment: I'm glad that led to a solution! To properly mark this as solved, and to make it as easy to find and understand as possible for other users in the future, you should [post your own answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). A couple days later you can even mark your own answer as accepted. It would also be okay for me to post an answer, but I think it's actually better for you to do so in this case, since although the link in my comment directed you to the solution, I didn't actually mention the most important part of the solution (that VPNs can cause this issue to occur) in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Running `ping ::1` as suggested by Elijah Kagen confirmed that the IPv6 address for `localhost` was being blocked. Based on the discussion at the page linked by him I concluded that my VPN was preventing livepatch from reaching the net. I disconnected the VPN and was able to enable livepatch normally.